# Cannot boot a MacBook Air M2 from an USB drive

Tags: macos, startup, security, external-disk, sonoma

I tried installing several macOS versions (Monterey, Ventura, Sonoma) on a Samsung USB-C drive (MUF-256DA) using a MacBook Air M2.

I disabled the MacBook's security from the startup options (recovery mode) so that it can boot from any signed release.

I tried several times using 3 methods:

1. Using the App Store to download and run the installer, then point it to the USB drive (after formatting it with GUID partition map and APFS)
2. Same download from App Store, then creating a separate USB installer with createinstallmedia, then booting from the USB installer to install onto the destination USB drive.
3. Running the installer from the Mac's recovery partition.

In all cases the installer completes without errors, but when the Mac tries booting from the newly installed USB drive it fails midway. If I enable verbose boot messages (with `sudo nvram boot-args="-v"`) I get the attached messages. (The yellow highlight is mine)

[image: boot error messages]

Here is a transcription of some of the messages:

```
effaceable_is_disabled:11856: ================ no-effaceable-storage is ON =================
effaceable_is_disabled:11856: ================ no-effaceable-storage is ON =================
effaceable_is_disabled:11856: ================ no-effaceable-storage is ON =================
effaceable_is_disabled:11856: ================ no-effaceable-storage is ON =================
AppleSEPKeyStore:5882:51: disabling use of effaceable storage, using fake key, Oxffffffff
_aks_unwrap_media_class:180: AKS unwrap_media_key_from_class succeeded for tag = 7 
fillEncryptionInfoForVolume:1299: disk2s1 apfs_vek_get_aks_state failed with error 22
fillEncryptionInfoForVolume:1299: disk2s2 apfs_vek_get_aks_state failed with error 22
fillEncryptionInfoForVolume:1299: disk2s3 apfs_vek_get_aks_state failed with error 22
fillEncryptionInfoForVolume:1299: disk2s4 apfs_vek_get_aks_state failed with error 22
fillEncryptionInfoForVolume:1299: disk2s6 apfs_vek_get_aks_state failed with error 22
.
.
.
AppleSEPKeyStore:7523:72: unexpected session uid: -1 requested by: PerfPowerServices (72)
AppleSEPKeyStore:12029:72: operation failed (sel: 17 ret: e00002c2, -1)
AppleSEPKeyStore:7523:72: unexpected session uid: -1 requested by: PerfPowerServices (72)
AppleSEPKeyStore:12029:72: operation failed (sel: 7 ret: e00002c2, -1)
```

Does anybody have any idea on what can I try?

---

Edit: I found **GPT-4's interpretation** of the above error messages useful:

The error messages you're seeing are related to the Apple M1 and M2 chips' security and encryption features. It appears that the system is trying to use effaceable storage, a type of secure storage used by Apple, but it's being disabled.

The `no-effaceable-storage is ON` message indicates that the system is not using effaceable storage. Effaceable storage is a secure area of the storage device where keys are stored for data encryption and decryption [Source 1](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/675850).

The `AppleSEPKeyStore:5882:51: disabling use of effaceable storage, using fake key, Oxffffffff` message is related to the Apple Secure Enclave Processor (SEP), which is part of the M1 and M2 chips. The SEP is responsible for handling encryption keys and secure boot. It appears that since the effaceable storage is disabled, the SEP is using a 'fake' key [Source 2](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/secure-enclave-seb49c0df60/web).

The `fillEncryptionInfoForVolume:1299: disk2s1 apfs_vek.get_aks_state failed with error 22` messages indicate that the system is having trouble accessing the APFS (Apple File System) volumes on the external drive. The 'error 22' typically signifies an invalid argument, meaning that something in the request to access the volume is not correct [Source 3](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/128225)

---

Also, **Phind V6's interpretation:**

The error messages you're seeing are related to the Apple Secure Enclave (ASE) and Apple Key Store (AKS), which are security features introduced with the M1 and M2 chips. The ASE is a coprocessor that handles cryptographic operations, while the AKS is a key storage service.

The `no-effaceable-storage` message indicates that the system is running in a mode where the secure enclave can't be erased. This is a normal state for systems that are running on non-Apple hardware, such as your external drive. The system will continue to function, but with reduced security because the secure enclave can't be erased if needed.

The `disabling use of effaceable storage, using fake key, Oxffffffff` message is indicating that the system is disabling the use of the secure enclave and instead using a "fake" key. This is also a normal state for systems running on non-Apple hardware.

The `apfs_vek.get_aks_state failed with error 22` messages are indicating that there was an error getting the state of the Apple Key Store. This could be due to a variety of reasons, such as a problem with the drive, a problem with the filesystem, or a problem with the AKS itself.

Unfortunately, these error messages alone aren't enough to determine the exact cause of the problem.

Comment: If you could link to the one procedure you followed rather saying that several don’t work, it might help us point out a better install reference.

Comment: My preferred [install method is using the App Store section](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683) only and running the installer. Is that a viable option for you?

Comment: @bmike Thank you. I tried 3 methods: 1. using the App Store to run the installer and point it to the USB drive (after formatting it with GUID partition map and APFS); 2. creating a separate USB installer with createinstallmedia, then booting from it to install onto the destination USB drive; 3. running the installer from the Mac's recovery partition. Same error message every time. Some links: https://appleinsider.com/inside/macos-ventura/tips/how-to-make-an-external-bootable-working-drive-in-macos-ventura - https://iboysoft.com/howto/install-macos-on-external-drive.html

Comment: Good details. Is the Mac running Sonoma already? If so you might want / need to rerun that while online to get non OS components upgraded.

Comment: @bmike I tried it both when the mac was running Ventura, and after upgrading it to Sonoma. But in the case of Sonoma, I didn't run the installer from the Macbook itself, I ran it from a different Mac. I could try again, downloading and running the Sonoma installer from the target Macbook itself while it's running Sonoma. But I don't think it will change anything. There is something more basic going on here that eludes me. See also GPT's insight that I posted above.

Comment: It does change things in my experience, the intstaller when run from the Mac itself performs additional installs and changes especially so on T2 and Apple Silicon Mac hardware.